# How to save each foreach data in session in laravel 6?

Tags: php, laravel

Currently when I want to delete someone from the database their information is stored within a hidden input field, which isn't safe.

```
@foreach($registered as $register)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$register->name}}</td>
        <td>{{$register->number}}</td>
        <td>{{$register->address}}</td>
        <td>{{$register->age}}</td>
        <td>{{$register->accountId}}</td>
        <td>
        <form action="removeFromRegister" method="post">
            @csrf
            @method('delete')
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$register->id}}">
            <input type="submit" value="Verwijder" class="btn btn-danger">
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Is there a better way to get the data from each foreach loop to send to the controller in laravel 6?

Comment: Why isn't it safe?

Comment: @apokryfos Someone could inspect and change the ID to a newly guessed ID and they aren't authorized to play with others' data. Of course,  a server validation on this should do good.

Comment: @vivek_23 But is that not the case with ANY data in an input form?

Comment: You need to [authorise](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/authorization) the request on the controller. Client side tricks aren't good enough

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes, hence validation is necessary ensuring that a user deals with only his resources.

Answer (score 1):

Your method is totally fine. But you need to add server-side code that checks that user modifies only the data he has access to. Check out [this portion of Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authorization) on how to authorise the Laravel way.